# debian cups can't add a printer

Tags: debian, printer, cups

I've installed cups and cups-client.

I'm in the lpadmin group.

Now when I click on 'Add Printer' in the Administration nothing happens.

The access log says it was successful though.

```
localhost - - [11/May/2012:13:43:49 +0200] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.0" 200 60 - -
localhost - - [11/May/2012:13:43:49 +0200] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.0" 200 4987 - -
```

EDIT: it does not work with localhost:631 or 127.0.0.1:631 but with the ipv6 version http://[::1]:631

EDIT2: contents of `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

EDIT3: changed the first line of the /etc/hosts to 127.0.0.1 localhost ipv4-localhost ipv4-loopback, still don't working. if I bind cups to 127.0.0.1 it is obviously not reachable via [::1]:631 but still not working via 127.0.0.1/localhost either.

Comment: i.e. with ipv6 it works? :) Also, what is the value of `AuthType` for `CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer` (if it is `Default` then provide `DefaultAuthType` too).

Comment: it only works with ipv6. DefaultAuthType is Basic and AuthType for everything in the config is Default.

Comment: good; now post contents of your `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: 1. try changing entry `127.0.0.1 localhost` in /etc/hosts -> `127.0.0.1 localhost ipv4-localhost ipv4-loopback` (restart cups after that); 2. you may also try to bind cups to ipv4 explicitely (by changing `Listen localhost:631` -> `Listen 127.0.0.1:631` in cups conf).